# Pandas - Create new DataFrame column using dot product of elements in each row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, vectorization, dot-product

I'm trying to take an existing DataFrame and append a new column.

Let's say I have this DataFrame (just some random numbers):

```
    a           b           c            d          e
0   2.847674    0.890958    -1.785646   -0.648289   1.178657
1   -0.865278   0.696976    1.522485    -0.248514   1.004034
2   -2.229555   -0.037372   -1.380972   -0.880361   -0.532428
3   -0.057895   -2.193053   -0.691445   -0.588935   -0.883624
```

And I want to create a new column 'f' that multiplies each row by a 'costs' vector, for instance [1,0,0,0,0]. So, for row zero, the output in column f should be 2.847674.

Here's the function I currently use:

```
def addEstimate (df, costs): 
   row_iterator = df.iterrows()

   for i, row in row_iterator:
      df.ix[i, 'f'] = np.dot(costs, df.ix[i])
```

I'm doing this with a 15-element vector, over ~20k rows, and I'm finding that this is super-duper slow (half an hour). I suspect that using `iterrows` and `ix` is inefficient, but I'm not sure how to correct this.

Is there a way that I can apply this to the entire DataFrame at once, rather than looping through rows?  Or do you have other suggestions to speed this up?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create the new column with `df['f'] = df.dot(costs)`.

`dot` is already a DataFrame method: applying it to the DataFrame as a whole will be much quicker than looping over the DataFrame and applying `np.dot` to individual rows.

For example:

```
>>> df # an example DataFrame
    a   b   c   d   e
0   0   1   2   3   4
1  12  13  14  15  16
2  24  25  26  27  28
3  36  37  38  39  40

>>> costs = [1, 0, 0, 0, 2]
>>> df['f'] = df.dot(costs)
>>> df
    a   b   c   d   e    f
0   0   1   2   3   4    8
1  12  13  14  15  16   44
2  24  25  26  27  28   80
3  36  37  38  39  40  116
```

Comment: Thanks, that was way simpler than I thought.

Answer (score 0):

Pandas has a dot function as well. Does

```
df['dotproduct'] = df.dot(costs)
```

do what you are looking for?

Comment: Looks like ajcr beat me to it!